# Catching exception with unreferenced local variable warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I've the following code:

```
try {
    // do some stuff
}
catch(const my_exception_type& e) {
    LOG("Exception %s", e.what());
    throw;
}
```

The problem is that in debug build the `LOG` is defined as `#define LOG(...)  real_logger(...)`, but in release build is defined as `#define LOG(...)   \\ do nothing`.

Of course when I'm compiling my release code in Visual Studio, I'm getting the `warning C4101: 'e' : unreferenced local variable`.

What is the best practice to handle exception logging without generation any unnecessary warnings?

**P.S** 
I'm doing nothing with the exception except logging and re-throwing it.

Comment: As a side note, this is exactly the behavior I'd need from my g++/clang++ compilers in order to solve this issue before my static analysis tool detects it as a flaw... no matter what level of verbosity I enable, they won't warn me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `#ifdef` each `catch` line (very invasive) or add just a line in each catch block:

```
catch(const my_exception_type& e) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);
    LOG("Exception %s", e.what());
    throw;
}
```

And the warning is gone. Or, you can `#define MY_EXCEPTION_CATCH(...)` to define the `e` parameter only in debug build.

Comment: `#ifdef` each `catch` line is something that I'm trying to ignore. What do you mean by adding `e;`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you add the line `e;` in each catch block, the compiler will consider that as a 'use' of the `e` variable... It's a trick to prevent the warning with the minimum code cluttering

Answer (score 8):

You can mark the object as "used" by casting it to void.
It has no influence on the generated machine code, but it will suppress the compiler warning.

```
try {
    // do some stuff
}
catch(const my_exception_type& e) {
    (void)e;
    LOG("Exception %s", e.what());
    throw;
}
```

Comment: It is interesting, there is another [sample](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/) by Herb Sutter that is using template function: `template<class T> void ignore( const T& ) { }`.
But are there other solutions?

Comment: There are probably multiple ways to tell the compiler that an object is somehow used. The `void` cast is quite well known. QT even provides the macro `Q_UNUSED(value)` for that, which is defined as follows: `#define Q_UNUSED(x) (void)x;`

Comment: `e=e` is another common idiom.

Comment: @Clifford: unfortunately, this may trigger a self-assignment that the compiler cannot optimize away (for user-defined types).

Comment: @Pupsik: This is the best option in general, and another is using a macro, because it *explains* what is going on. In your case, modifying the `LOG` macro to avoid this; you could define `LOG` in release to cast to `void` (each argument).

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Your code just threw an exception, optimisation is the least concern at that point perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford: Not necessarily, if your code is too slow on the error path, then an onslaught of "wrong" inputs may cause a DoS. Thus, at least it should be as fast as the regular path.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Goot point - worth highlighting the idiom then just so the unwary (like me perhaps) know why they should not do it! - it is common in C but should not be copied in C++.